# Dagger does not throw exception if a subcomponent has conflicting scope with one of the parent components

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

ComponentA (scopeA)
ComponentB (scopeB, dependencies = ComponentA)
ComponentC (scopeC, dependecies = ComponentB)
SubcomponentD (scopeA, created from ComponentC).

No exception is thrown though D has conflict with A ([code](https://github.com/guliash/DaggerExamples/tree/component-subcomponent-same-scopes/app/src/main/java/com/guliash/daggerexamples))

If we leave only
ComponentA (scopeA)
SubcomponentD (scopeA, created from ComponentA)
then the conflicting scopes exception will be thrown.

Why in the first case no exception thrown?

I created an [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/808) but no answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. A subcomponent is a part of its parent component (not any ancestor subcomponent). So Dagger checks the scopes hierarchy for each component (not for the whole graph). See [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/391aeebf4fff0af03bfadb10121455592cbbba6d/java/dagger/internal/codegen/ComponentHierarchyValidator.java#L108).